# Testing the difference between 2 prevalence ratios

Tags: prevalence

I want to test if prevalence ratio (a disease in Men vs Women) in population A is statistically different from population B. I wonder what statistical test can be used?

Comment: Hello, LOH, and welcome to the site!  We would need a lot more information than you've provided us to answer that question, e.g., what data do you have that underlies the prevalence ratio calculations, how was the experiment performed (natural experiment or otherwise...).

Comment: Hi jbowman, Let me explain the question better. If there are 2 prevalence ratios. The one for population A, PR_A = [M_DA/(M_DA+M_NA)]/[W_DA/(W_DA+W_NA)], where PR_A = prevalence ratio for population A, M_DA = no. of men with Disease in population A, M_NA = no. of men with No disease in population A, W_DA = no. of women with Disease in population A, W_NA = no. of women with No disease in population A. Similarly, for population B, we have prevalence ratio PR_B calculated the same way. Population A and B are two independent samples, I want to test if PR_A is statistically different from PR_B.